# Android - Custom ListView creating the right number of entries but only populating the first one

Tags: java, android, listview

So the thing is, I create a custom ListView which shows a layout I created as entries, when the entry is created it loads the data I gave it and populates the layout components, thing is, it's creating the right number of entries but only the first entry components are getting the data loaded.
I have actually no idea what is wrong with this.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tarde.multimvideo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lista;
    private Button btnPlay;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

        ArrayList<Entrada> datos = new ArrayList<Entrada>();
        datos.add(new Entrada(R.drawable.nino, "Video 1", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20660499/video.mp4"));
        datos.add(new Entrada(R.drawable.pajaro, "Video 2", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20660499/video1.mp4"));
        datos.add(new Entrada(R.drawable.casa, "Video 3", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20660499/video2.mp4"));

        lista.setAdapter(new Lista_adaptador(this, R.layout.entrada, datos) {
            @Override
            public void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view) {
                if(entrada != null) {
                    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
                    if(img != null) {
                        img.setImageResource(((Entrada) entrada).getImagen());
                    }
                    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblInfo);
                    if(t != null) {
                        t.setText(((Entrada) entrada).getInfo());
                    }
                    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblUrl);
                    if(t != null) {
                        t.setText(((Entrada)entrada).getUrl());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Entrada e = (Entrada)lista.getSelectedItem();
                if(e != null) {
                    url = e.getUrl();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Video.class);
                    i.putExtra("url", url);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void play(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Lista_Adaptador.java

```
package com.example.tarde.multimvideo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Tarde on 17/11/2015.
 */
public abstract class Lista_adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<?> entradas;
    private int layout;
    private Context contexto;

    public Lista_adaptador(Context contexto, int layout, ArrayList<?> entradas) {
        super();
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.entradas = entradas;
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicion, View view, ViewGroup pariente) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(layout, null);
        }
        onEntrada (entradas.get(posicion), view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return entradas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int posicion) {
        return entradas.get(posicion);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int posicion) {
        return posicion;
    }

    /** Devuelve cada una de las entradas con cada una de las vistas a la que debe de ser asociada
     * @param entrada La Entrada que será la asociada a la view. La Entrada es del tipo del paquete/handler
     * @param view View particular que contendrá los datos del paquete/handler
     */
    public abstract void onEntrada (Object entrada, View view);

}
```

And now the absurd result:
[Absurd result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAQdH.png)

Thanks for the quick responses guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
 @Override
        public void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view) {
            if(entrada != null) {
                ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
                if(img != null) {
                    img.setImageResource(((Entrada) entrada).getImagen());
                }
                TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblInfo);
                if(t != null) {
                    t.setText(((Entrada) entrada).getInfo());
                }
                t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblUrl);
                if(t != null) {
                    t.setText(((Entrada)entrada).getUrl());
                }
            }
        }
```

You are calling `findViewbyID()`, but you are calling it on your activity, not on the view passed to your `onEntrada()` method.  So the activity is finding the first matching view, which is the first view in your list.  Instead, replace each `findViewByID()` with `view.findViewByID()` so that you limit the scope that is searched to the view in your list, rather than the entire view of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the activity's *findViewById* to get the views, but it is not restricted to any entry of your list.

On method *onEntrada* you have the parameter *view*, use it to get the elements.

For example, when you have

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

change to

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
```